# Yesod not routing to handler

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-stack

I am with a scaffolded yesod (`yesod 1.4.1.5`) application using the stack tool. I cannot get a new route to work.

```
# config/routes
/static StaticR Static appStatic
/auth   AuthR   Auth   getAuth

/favicon.ico FaviconR GET
/robots.txt RobotsR GET

/trails TrailsR  GET

/ HomeR          GET POST
```

Then I defined the following module:

```
-- Handler/Trails.hs
module Handler.Trails where

import Import
--import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3 (BootstrapFormLayout (..), renderBootstrap3,
--                              withSmallInput)

getTrailsR :: Handler Html
getTrailsR = defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
    $(widgetFile "trails")
```

I made the trails template file:

```
-- templates/trails.hamlet
<h1>All Trails A-Z

<ul>
  <li>Hi
```

I did not create the `.julius` or `.lucius` files. Does that matter?

And I made sure to put the module in `Application.hs`:

```
-- Import all relevant handler modules here.
-- Don't forget to add new modules to your cabal file!
import Handler.Common
import Handler.Home
import Handler.Trails
```

And I made sure to register that module in the `onh.cabal` for the project, here's the full library stanza:

```
library
    hs-source-dirs: ., app
    exposed-modules: Application
                     Foundation
                     Import
                     Import.NoFoundation
                     Model
                     Settings
                     Settings.StaticFiles
                     Handler.Common
                     Handler.Home
                     Handler.Trails
```

Then I boot the app as such: `stack exec -- yesod devel` but it still doesn't comes back as a 404:

```
$ curl -v localhost:3000/trails
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /trails HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 05:00:17 GMT
* Server Warp/3.1.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: Warp/3.1.2
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug that routes are wired up correctly and hooked in to the build system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be affected by a bug [described on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/yesodweb/Ch1qTEHrqUE/jcVazJo4BgAJ). Upgrading to yesod-bin-1.4.14 should fix that issue. Can you try that and see if it works?